# How do I install Manjaro without USB?

Tags: manjaro

I am thinking of switching my desktop to Manjaro. I have all backup files in another hard disk. I just want to remove Windows and install Manjaro. Currently I have given my USB to one of my friend keeping there some file. She said she would return me in a week. How do I install Manjaro without USB?

Comment: Borrow another USB from another friend?

Answer (score 1):

Is downloading the ISO and burning to a CD/DVD an option?  Guidance on how to [Burn an ISO File](https://wiki.manjaro.org/index.php/Burn_an_ISO_File) is at the Manjaro Wiki.